# Basic difference between types intergation?

Tags: integration

I want know basic idea of difference between line integral , surface integral and volume integral and normal integration ?

Comment: Your question is too broad. What don't you understand after reading the relevant Wikipedia pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a scalar line integral $\int_C f(\textbf{x})d\textbf{s}$, which is a scalar function $f$ over a parametrized curve $C$

There's a vector line integral $\int_C \textbf{F}(\textbf{x})\cdot d\textbf{s}$, which is a vector field $\textbf{F}$ over a parametrized curve $C$

There's a scalar surface integral $\int\int_D f(\textbf{x}) dA$, which is a scalar function $f$ over a parametrized region $D$, and can be regarded as a volume.  We can also have $\int\int\int_W f(\textbf{x}) dV$, which can be regarded as a kind of "mass" for density function $f$.

There's a vector surface integral $\int\int_D \textbf{F}(\textbf{x}) \cdot d\textbf{S}$ and $\int\int\int_W \textbf{F}(\textbf{x}) \cdot d\textbf{S}$

Of course there's a normal integral $\int_a^b f(x) dx$

And there's probably plenty others I've missed, such as contour integrals and complex integrals and the more abstract stuff as well.